# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'l.createTargets')

Tags: ios, react-native

Trying to run on iOS but getting this error. I could not find any explanation for days now.

undefined is not an object (evaluating 'l.createTargets')

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) along with what you've already attempted in trying to solve your problem. If you're not sure how to best formulate your question, please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MichaelCheng is right, show some code. Such errors can happen in many occassions.

Comment: 2019-06-25 12:49:36.298 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined is not an object (evaluating 'l.createTargets')
2019-06-25 12:49:36.362 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.ExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'l.createTargets')
2019-06-25 12:49:36.364 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: That is the message I get

Comment: I used Viro React Native to build this project. Everything was going just fine, and out of nothing, as it seems to me, this error came out

Comment: Just the error log is not enough. You need to provide some details: the codes that u used, your environment, etc.